# How to remove unwanted languages from django oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I just want a few languages, how can I hide or disable the ones I don't want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define in your settings.py file languages that you want to be enabled:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', _("German")),
    ('en', _("English")),
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just figured that out myself!