# How to remove or disable unwanted languages in Django 4.1.1

Tags: python, django

I had a question about translations in Django...
So I have a project with 4 languages defined in my settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('it', _('Italy')),
]
```

now I want to disable all languages except english, so I've been searching in google how to do it, and find this post on SO => [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651706/how-to-remove-unwanted-languages-from-django-oscar), than I tried to comment all languages except english, after that I've done `./manage.py makemigrations` => `./manage.py migrate` migrations went without any error, BUT in my language list they didn't dissapear... also I've been find code that as I think forms this list... I changed thare hardcoded langlist from `language_list = ['en', 'it', 'de', 'fr']` to `language_list = settings.LANGUAGES` and also nothing happened with my UI language list choices...

So, question:
how properly I can disable unwanted languages in my Django application;

P.S I'm new in python and Django at all, so please can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define it in the setting's file in the `LANGUAGES` list.

In your case, it should be English only, and make sure you are running migrations correctly. Please double-check the migrations file and run migrate command again, and it should work.

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _("English")),
)
```

Comment: and in migrations I should find only removeRow for specific language? because in my migration file I had only removeRow rowName_lang

Answer (score 0):

problem solved
I just should populate language list in UI from settings.py (using this package => https://github.com/jakubroztocil/django-settings-export), and this solved my problem!